# What lifecycle method is the proper one to run validations in child component on button click in another child component?

Tags: reactjs, methods, components, lifecycle

I have a parent component and 3 child component. first 2 child components have input fields. 3rd child component have a submit button. When I click submit button, validations to check for empty field should run on both the other 2 components.

What is the best way to do this? Which life cycle method is the proper one to use?

Answer (score 0):

ok so in this case parent component needs to save the state of both first 2 child components, and when you click on submit button in 3rd child component then there are two ways:

1) method of submit button should also be in parent state. (recommended -- aka Lifting State: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

2) pass a props to 3rd child from parent which should tell child #3 that child#1 and child#2 fields are validated ex:

```
<childThree isFormValidated={this.state.isFormValidated} />
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm already using the state of first 2 child components inside the child components itself for various other uses. I need those to be there. I was thinking of some other way. Like when I click button, parent component should set a state start validating = true and then pass this state to child components. Once the child component receive this, run validations. But I'm stuck as to which lifecycle method should the child component use?

Comment: @Jeny Hi,
"I'm already using the state of first 2 child components inside the child components "

By this: " inside the child components" you mean using first two childs state in 3rd child?

Comment: @Jeny 
This is how it is setup , right?:
`
              Parent
      /            |           \
child#1  child#2     child#3
`

Comment: state of each component inside the component itself. This is for running the validations on blur event for each text field.

Comment: ok so parent has 3 children: child#1, child#2, and child#3.

Each child is keeping its own state right now for validation.

So now we have two options:
1) pass child#1 and child#2 validation states to child#3 through parent
2) or keep the validation state of child#1 and child#2 in parent (instead of passing to child#3 like in step#1), also bring submit method to parent.

Comment: ok so parent has 3 children: child#1, child#2, and child#3.

Each child is keeping its own state right now for validation.

So now we have two options:
1) pass child#1 and child#2 validation states to child#


For updated answer:
> But I'm stuck as to which lifecycle method should the child component use?

 you can use `componentdidupdate`: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Thanks. Let me take a look at componentDidUpdate